# How to hash stored passwords in mysql using pbkdf2_sha256 using Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication

I have list of user passwords stored as plain text. I think I need a script to run over the stored passwords and hash them. I'm new to Django and not sure where to start or how.

I created login and creating accounts only works for new users:

```
@admin_login_required
def add_emp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST['user_name']
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_otj = request.POST['user_otj']
        user_password = pwo.generate()
        user_password1 = make_password(user_password)
        empObj = User.objects.create(user_name=user_name, user_email=user_email, user_password=user_password1, user_otj=user_otj)
        if empObj:
            subject = 'Advanced Analytics Portal - Login Info'
            message = f'Name : {user_name}, \n Email : {user_email}, \n Password : {user_password} \n FROM - AA Portal'
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [user_email])
            messages.success(request, "Employee was added successfully!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Some error was occurred!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
    return render(request, 'AddEmp.html')

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).first()

        if user_details and check_password(user_password, user_details.user_password):
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details.user_name
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

How can I make previous users log in without creating new accounts for them.

Comment: If you have already stored user passwords in plain text, you cannot hash them now since hashing is a one-way process. Instead, you will need to reset all existing user passwords and ask them to create new passwords. You can use Django's built-in `make_password` function to hash passwords.

Comment: Yes I’m dealing with a db with stored plain text passwords. Is there a way to loop over the passwords and put them in a make_password function?

Comment: From security perspective, all the passwords should be reset. You can enforce that my simply replacing password with random password. 
If you have shell access to django, you can use `./manage.py shell` to access Django shell. Here is pretty extensive tutorial: https://www.nickmccullum.com/useful-features-django-shell/
What I would do is I'd simply put a random string for every user password and force them reset that way. Of course, communication is needed: Hey guys, we are improving our application security. In order to do that, we need you all to reset your password.  etc...

Comment: @JHS99 Do you mean how to convert old users plain text passwords to hashed passwords? As I can see you're already using `make_password()` method to has the passwords of new users, but you want old users' passwords to be hashed.

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes exactly I’m asking if there’s a way to hash old passwords the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`make_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) to hash the password and [`is_password_usable()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.is_password_usable) to avoid re-hashing already hashed passwords by checking whether the password is hashed or not.

Write a script or a management command to loop over the existing `User` objects and update their passwords, like following:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, is_password_usable
from myapp.models import User

def hash_existing_passwords():
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if not is_password_usable(user.password):
            continue
        user.password = make_password(user.password)
        user.save()


hash_existing_passwords()
```

You can run this script using the following command:

```
python manage.py shell < path/to/script.py
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help! many thanks I got all passwords hashed as expected!